# sequelize: retrieve model of a manually created table

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

If i create tables with sequelize API (sequelize.define), it returns a model object (*User* in the following example) that i can use to do queries (User.find) and other kind of operations:

```
var User = sequelize.define('User', {/* ... */})
```

If i need to create a table in the db without that api, but i need to do it with a pure sql query, is there a way to retrieve the same model object for my manual table and use it like the others?

In *sequelize.models* i see all my tables but not the custom one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define a model using `define` with the `tableName` property set to your manually defined table.

The DB columns that you want to retrieve as a model's attributes must meet a number of criteria. Each should have a datatype that matches the column's type. They should have the same constraints (cascade, null etc) as the DB columns. The column name should either match what Sequelize automatically generates or be specified manually using `field`.

Since the table for this model has already been manually created, make sure that it is not `sync`'ed to the DB. To test that the model you have specified will work the manually specified table you should sync the model to a test database and compare the automatically generated SQL with the manually generated SQL You are using.

This answer is based on the documentation [here](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/models-definition/).